# How to call a random function of a class in c++?

Tags: c++, function, random, header

I am trying to create a command-line game in `C++`. I am new to it and just started learning.
My game consists of a player class and a dragon class. The classes are declared in separate header files.
What I would like to know is, if there is a way to call a random function of a class after declaration.
Like

```
// ignore the includes
class foo{
    public:
        string name = "foo";
        foo(string name){
            this->name = name;
        }

        void func1(){
            //some code
        }

        void func2(){
            //some code
        }

        void func3(){
            //some code
        }
}


/////
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
    foo bar("hello");
    //call a random function like func1, func2, func3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use a switch( randomNumber ) { case 1: func1(); break; ... or use an array of function pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a beginner myself and I am sure there are much easier/better solutions than mine.

You can try it with cases.

```
int random_val = rand();
int nr = random_val % 3; 
switch (nr) {
    case 0: bar.func1();
            break;
    case 1: bar.func2();
            break;
    case 2: bar.func3();
            break;
    default:
            std::cout << "Default case" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's generally preferable to frame your answers as statements rather than questions. I've edited to show what I mean. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 3):

You can make an array with the given functions and generate a random int as an index into the array:

```
void invoke_random_function(foo& bar)
{
    //make an array of pointers to desired functions
    using func_type = void(foo::*)();
    constexpr func_type funcs[] = {
        &foo::func1,
        &foo::func2,
        &foo::func3
    };
    
    //select a random function from array
    auto random_index = (std::rand() % std::size(funcs)); //use better RNG than std::rand if necessary
    auto random_func = funcs[random_index];

    //invoke the selected function with the given instance of the class         
    (bar.*random_func)(); //funny notation to invoke member function pointers
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to use a std::vector or std::array (that way the size is a simple member function call), and std::functions instead of raw function pointers so that the invocation syntax isn't so arcane.

Comment: Can you explain how to provide as an array and call invoke function in the main as I am a beginner i don't understand pointers yet.

Comment: To call invoke_random_function from main you simply do `foo bar("hello"); invoke_random_function(bar);`, and then a random function will be invoked. I don't understand what you mean by "how to provide as array", could you elaborate on that?

Comment: its ok , I got how to do it, but you said "You can make an array with the given functions", so i got confused, thank you